# FromForm with IFormFile using Asp.net Core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iformfile

I want to upload an Image file with Model data so I am using `FromForm` with `IFormFile` in `Asp.net core` api.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddData([FromForm] AddDataModel addDataModel, IFormFile formFile)
{
     // Logic here...
}
```

I am using `Angular 7` in the frontend side. I am adding model data and file to `FormData` and trying to send it but It always all model fields values null.

What is the right way to solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The formfile has to be inside your `AddDataModel` csharp class.

Like this

```
public class AddDataModel 
{
   public IFormFile File { get; set; }
   // more properties
}
```

Then in your angular-service, do the following

```
public add(model: AddDataModel): Observable<any> { // file can be passed as parameter or inside typescript model
   const formData = new FormData();
   // optional you can pass a file name as third parameter
   formData.append('file', model.file)
   // add more keys to the form-data
   return this.http.post<any>('my-http-url', formData);
}
```

Now update the endpoint

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddData([FromForm] AddDataModel addDataModel)
{
     // Logic here...
}
```

Now the modelbinder of ASP.NET Core will map the form file retrieved from the form-data.

**Edit:**

Added a simple sample on [github](https://github.com/alsami/asp-net-core-angular-file-upload) ready to be cloned.

Comment: Do I need to remove `IFromFile` from API method level?

Comment: Yes, it will only be inside your csharp class.

Comment: It worked. As `FormData` doesn't accept Model, I need to use `JSON.stringify` so API is not validating Model through a filter. How do I solve it?

Comment: If you're using `FormData` then you actually have to build your form data with that. You can't just create a JSON string of a complex object and pass the string. You may be better served here by actually submitting JSON, instead. For your file upload, you simply need to read the file bytes and create a Base 64 encoded string to pass in your JSON. Server-side, you'll bind that to a byte[] instead of `IFormFile` then.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I was using Base 64 encoded string before but sometimes, if file size is large then it hangs up the browser.

Comment: Updated ther answer with the sample.